# in memory of or with memories of

Tags: prepositions

I have to make a dedication plaque.
do I write "restored in memory of blah blah and blah"  or "restored with memories of blah blah and blah"
thanks.. oh yea, blah blah and blah are people's names...

Comment: "Restored with memories of..." suggests you used the memories to restore whatever it is. I suspect you used something more concrete.

Comment: thanks.   Yea, the Waiting Room was restored by funds that were given in memory of my folks... so I guess it should be "Waiting Room restored in memory of Fannie Z., William B. and Jeffrey Z. Mantel"... right?

Comment: Is it ok if I say "in fond memory of"

Comment: "In fond memory" sounds rather lukewarm compared to "In loving memory", I feel.

Comment: I don't want it to be mushy. because the money was donated by someone who barely knew them.   So maybe I'll just leave it plain..  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

"In memory of …" would be the most common phrasing on such dedications (followed by using the Latin *In memoriam …*). More generally, while something done to memorialise someone is of course done "with memories", we use "in memory" for such acts.

Comment: thanks.   Yea, the Waiting Room was restored by funds that were given in memory of my folks... so I guess it should be "Waiting Room restored in memory of Fannie Z., William B. and Jeffrey Z. Mantel"... right?

Answer (score 1):

"In memory of" is an idiom referring to commemorating a deceased person, or an event in which people died. I don't suggest varying the syntax. Modifiers such as "fond" or "loving" are common.

**Edit:** clarified in response to comments.

Comment: is it ok if I saw "in fond memory of"  then 3 names

Comment: @Hen Yes, modifiers like that are common.